# Storing array variables from HTML form in PHP and using values to calculate sum

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a HTML form with an array as checkboxes. I am trying to pass the checked values to the php and then using it to calculate the sum. At the moment my array values are not getting passed and i am not sure how i can use the passed array to calculate a sum. Please guide me in the right direction.

My Form HTML:

```
<tr>
            <td>four 100 watt light bulbs for $2</td>
            <td align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]"  value="2"/></td></tr>

<tr>
            <td>eight 100 watt light bulbs for $4</td>
            <td align="center">
<input type="checkbox" name="items[]"  value="4"/></td></tr>

Battery Packs : 
<input type="text" name="batterypack" value="10.42">
<br>
```

My PHP code:

```
$bulbs = $_POST['items[]'] ; 
echo $_POST['items[]'] ;

$batterypack = $_POST['batterypack'];
echo $_POST['batterypack'];
```

How can I add all the ticked checkboxes and print a sum? and also multiply the number they type inside the "batterypack" with $10.42 and produce a sum too?

Comment: how can i add all the ticked checkboxes and print a sum? and also multiply the number they type inside the "batterypack" with $10.42 and produce a  sum too?

Comment: what does `var_dump($_POST['items']);` returns ?

Comment: it returns array(1) { [0]=> string(3) when executed

Comment: Have you checked all the checkbox for the test ? And after `string(3)` there is a string normally, have you paste all the output ?

Comment: sorry it outputs: array(1) { [0]=> string(3) "3.9" }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could get the sum with

```
array_sum($_POST['items']);
```

but don't forget to check if it is defined first !

```
if (!empty($_POST['items'])
{
    // your code here
    $var = 10.42;
    $sum = array_sum($_POST['items']);
    $res = $sum * $var;
    print_r($res);
}
```

Comment: That works perfectly! but how can i convert the number the user enters inside the batterypack text box and multiply it with 10.42?

Comment: I have edit my answer to show you how to do it. Don't forget to mark your question as resolved ;-)